# Do I have to use the <BrowserRouter> when I want to use <Route> in ReactJs?

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

In a course a took he didn't use the `<BrowserRouter>`. But in a project of mine I was getting the `Invariant failed: You should not use <Link> outside a <Router>` error. Why?

Comment: Are you sure there wasn't a router in the course?

Comment: It would be helpful if you provided a bit more code in your question.  It sounds like you have used the link tag outside the router tag.  But without more code one can't confirm that is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it's my fault. I didn't remember that he changed the default to  the BrowserRouter in the index.js.Sorry!

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <BrowserRouter>
    <App />
  </BrowserRouter>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```